# What registers are considered "address registers" in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-architecture, terminology, cpu-registers

Which registers are considered to be "Address registers" in Assembly? I thought that the answer would be something like: all segment registers, plus `EBP`, `ESP`, and `EIP` since they contain "addresses", if I can say that. But to my surprise the correct answer actually is: the segment registers and `EIP`. I couldn't find any type of explanation for this, tough. Why is it that the segment registers and `EIP` are called "address registers"? Why these registers specifically and not some others registers? (P.S. I'm using x86 NASM if it makes any difference)

Comment: Some architectures (like M68k) have dedicated address registers.  X86 just has general purpose registers, though in 16 bit mode, only `bx`, `si`, `di`, and `bp` could be used for explicit memory operands (`sp` is used for a bunch of implicit memory operands).  However, the word “address registers” is not commonly used to describe anything on x86.  Where does the statement about segment registers, `ebp`, `esp`, and `eip` being “address registers” come from?

Comment: That is just a question of definition. Anyway, I don't think anybody considers segment registers address registers. `EIP` isn't even a directly accessible register, but that is used by the cpu as an address. Similarly certain instructions implicitly use `ESP`, `ESI`, `EDI` and `EBP` as addresses but you can use any of those and the rest of the GPRs explicitly, e.g. `[EAX]`.

Comment: "address register" doesn't have a specific technical meaning that works across ISAs.  There's no widely-agree rule that makes this choice of classification correct but others incorrect.  "address register" in the m68k sense implies that it's mostly usable for holding pointers, but you can't use the program counter as a data pointer.  (And 32-bit x86 doesn't even have RIP-relative addressing.)  So whoever is making up classifications here is using a different interpretation.

Comment: The segment *registers* are clearly not normal address registers.  In protected mode they select a GDT entry.  The internal/hidden segment *base* holds an actual linear address, though.  (For FS and GS, accessible via `wrmsr` to `MSR_FS_BASE` / `MSR_GS_BASE`.  For the others, only via modifying the selector to trigger loading a new descriptor.)

Comment: Basically I don't think it's a very useful concept to apply, not if you do it this way.  An interesting question is how many data pointers can your keep in registers such that any one of them can be used, e.g. how many arrays can you loop over at once without running out of registers.  "how many address registers does m68k have?  8 including the stack pointer".  But this is not a useful definition for comparing x86 to other ISAs.  Especially given that x86 is almost universally used with ss.base = cs.base = ds.base = es.base flat memory model.

Comment: Well, not the 8-bit register parts in 16-bit mode, and not the 8- or 16-bit register parts in 32-bit mode, and not the 8- ,16-, or 32-bit register parts in 64-bit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 80x86, there is no clear and authoritative definition of "address register"; and (unless there is a clear and authoritative definition - e.g. in the CPU manufacturer's manual) "address register" could be defined as anything you like.

For one example, for 80x86, you could say that all general purpose registers can be used as an address (e.g. "`mov eax,[eax]`" or "`mov eax,[ebx]`" or ..) and therefore all general purpose registers are "address registers".

For another example, for 80x86, you could say that segment registers contain a structure of stuff (visible value, base address, limit, type) and are therefore not "address registers", and almost all normal registers (`EIP`, `ESP`, `ESI`, `EDI`, ...) can only contain an offset within a segment (which is not an address on its own) and are therefore also not "address registers"; and that there are no address registers at all.

Comment: In x86-64, where segment bases are fixed at 0, it's easier to argue that the GP-integer regs are "address registers" in that sense: linear address = offset, unless you override to FS or GS base.  But yeah, interesting point for protected and real modes.

Comment: @PeterCordes: For another example, for 64-bit code in 80x86, you could say there are "virtual address registers" (GDTR, IDTR, `rip`, `rsp`) and some "physical address registers" (`cr3`, local APIC base address MSR) but no "address registers" because that doesn't make sense when there's 2 (or more) different types of addresses. ;-)

Comment: As they say, there are only 2 hard problems in computing: naming things, and cache invalidation.  By that argument, m68k's address registers become "virtual address registers" if the system has an MMU.  (Although that's slightly different because an MMU is optional for m68k, but x86-64 long mode requires paging to be enabled.)

Comment: Also should be mentioned that AVX introduced VSIB addressing, where XMM0..ZMM31 play the role of **index addressing registers** in  gather/scatter instructions, such as https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vgatherdpd:vgatherqpd

Answer (score 1):

There are no doubt one or some instruction sets that to address something you have to use a specific register or set of registers.  But that is the exception not the rule.

For the instruction set in question simply look up the documentation and look for the load/store/read/write/mov/etc instructions that can address memory and look at the encodings and that will show a list of the registers for that architecture that can be used to hold addresses for address transactions (or at times an immediate may be in the instruction itself that is the address instead of being in a register).

For x86 will go against some of the comments and say that the segment registers in particular are address registers as their content is specifically used to generate an address.  Not on it's own it is combined with other bits to create the full address.  But their purpose and content is used in address generation.  I would certainly not use the term address register by itself to describe them though.